# How lim sups here converted to appropriate limits?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

This question is from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis :

> Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}$: $\{\frac 12, \frac 13, \frac 1{2^2}, \frac1{3^2}, \frac 1{2^3}, \frac1{3^3},\frac 1{2^4}, \frac1{3^4},\dots\}$ 
>   so, $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac 12\left(\frac32\right)^n$$ and $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n)^{\frac1n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)^{\frac1 {2n}}$$

I can't understand how did we get expressions like $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac 12\left(\frac32\right)^n$ or $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)^{\frac1 {2n}}$.

Limsup is defined in book as follows: Let $s_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $E$ be the set of numbers $x$ (in the extended real number system) such that $s_{n_k}\rightarrow x$ for some subsequence $s_{n_k}$. We denote upper limit of $s_n$ as $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_n=\sup E.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sequences start off with $n = 0$, we have $$\frac {a_{2k+1}}{a_{2k}} = \frac{\frac 1 {3^k}}{\frac 1 {2^k}} = \left(\frac 2 3\right)^k \tag{1}$$

$$\frac {a_{2k+2}}{a_{2k+1}} = \frac{\frac 1 {2^{k+1}}}{\frac 1 {3^k}} = \frac 1 2\left(\frac 3 2\right)^k\tag{2}$$

These two sequences together contain every element of $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. (1) converges to $0$, (2) diverges to $\infty$ (converges to $\infty$ in the extended reals). Any subsequence of $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ will have $0$ as a limit point if and only if it contains an infinite number of elements of (1) and will have $\infty$ as a limit point (or will diverge) if and only if it contains an infinite number of elements of (2). No other limit points are possible.

Since $\infty > 0$, (2) is a subsequence of $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ which converges to the highest limit, so the limit supremum will be the limit of this subsequence.

Similar remarks apply to the other limit.

Comment: Thank you so much, just one question: 'Odd numbered' subsequence of $(a_n)^{\frac1n}$ is $\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)^{\frac1{2n+1}}$, so how did he take $\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)^{\frac1{2n}}$?

Comment: By being a little careless. Understand that the sequences $a_n^{\frac 1 n}$ and $a_n^{\frac 1 {n+k}}$ have exactly the same limit behavior. In the extended reals, they both have exactly the same limit points. In particular, one will converge if and only if the other does, and to the same limit. So Rudin was not particularly bothered by being off by one in the index, and didn't bother to make sure the expression lined up exactly right.